# Passing boolean info from one class to another in Java

Tags: java

Good evening.

I have two classes - Car and EntryPoint.  There is a third class which is used to get name data, but that is not problematic hence I have omitted it from this question.

My problem is that I need to establish if the owners car has a large tank above a certain value. If so, I want to output "inefficient fuel use". If the tank size is below said value, I want it to output "good fuel consumption". If the tank size is a specific value, I want it to output "average consumption".  No problem there, however, I am getting a stack overflow error and I can't understand where my code is erroneous. Please advise.

My full source code for both classes follows...

```
// instance variables
private String model;
private int tankSize;
private double manfMPG;
private String ownerName;

public boolean tankBigger;


public void setBiggerTank(boolean hasBiggerTank) {
    this.tankBigger = hasBiggerTank;
}

// there are 0.22 gallons per litre
final double GPL = 0.22;


// parameterised constructor
public Car(String m, int t, double mpg, String owner)
{
    model = m;
    tankSize = t;
    manfMPG = mpg;
    ownerName = owner;
}

// default constructor
public Car()
{
    model = "";
    tankSize = 0;
    manfMPG = 0.0;
    ownerName = "";
}

// setters and getters
public String getModel() {
    return model;
}

public void setModel(String model) {
    this.model = model;
}

public int getTankSize() {
    return tankSize;
}

public void setTankSize(int tankSize) {
    this.tankSize = tankSize;
    
}

public double getManfMPG() {
    return manfMPG;
}

public void setManfMPG(double manfMPG) {
    this.manfMPG = manfMPG;
}

public double getEstimateDistance() {
    // there are 0.22 gallons per litre
    return tankSize * manfMPG * GPL;
}

public boolean hasBiggerTank() {
    
    if (tankSize >= 4) {
        System.out.println("inefficient fuel use");
    }
    else if (tankSize <= 2) {
        System.out.println("good fuel consumption");
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("Average consumer");
    }
    return hasBiggerTank();
}
```

}

---

```
public static void main(String [] args) {
    
    Car car1 = new Car();
    car1.setModel("Ferrari");
    car1.setTankSize(4);
    car1.setManfMPG(4);
    
    Name name1 = new Name("Kieran ", "David ", "Nock "); 
            
    System.out.println("Car 1 Model: " + car1.getModel());
    System.out.println("Car 1 tank size: " + car1.getTankSize());
    System.out.println("Car 1 ManfMPG: " + car1.getManfMPG());
    System.out.println("Car 1 estimated distance: " + car1.getEstimateDistance());
    System.out.println("Car 1 efficiency: " + (car1.hasBiggerTank() ? "inefficient fuel use" : "good fuel consumption"));
    System.out.println("Car 1 owner: " + name1.getFirstName() + name1.getMiddleName() + name1.getSurname());
    System.out.println("Car 1 owner sn: " + name1.getSurname());
    System.out.println("car 1 owner sn, fn: " + name1.getLastCommaFirst());
                
            
}
```

}

Comment: `return hasBiggerTank();` calls itself recursively forever. Well, at least until stack overflow.

Comment: As a general rule: Avoid side effects is methods that are named like a question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is caused by the `hasBiggerTank` method. It ends with calling itself which results in an endless loop which eventually will result in a stack overflow.

You can either return `true` (or `false` for that matter) but since the only thing this method does is logging to the console, I would suggest to change the return type of this method to void. This way you don't have to return anything at all.